# Error occured during signup in android project

Tags: java, android, firebase, heroku, error-handling

[image: signup page of the android project]

Here is a screenshot that describes my issue This is a trip planner android app. And this is my major project. as shown in the image while trying to signup it says doctype html in the snack bar.

I thought it was a backend server issue and tried connecting to the firebase server. But it doesn't work it shows the same error message.

I have identified that the code consists of a heroku link which is currently not working so I am facing an issue to signup. Is there any alternative that I can use instead of heroku link. here is some code of LoginActivity.java

```
public void login(boolean showToastMessage) {
    mView.openLogin(showToastMessage);
}

/**
 * Calls Login API and checks for validity of credentials
 * If yes, transfer to MainActivity
 *
 * @param email user's email id
 * @param pass  password user entered
 */
public void ok_login(final String email, String pass, final Handler mhandler) {

    mView.showLoadingDialog();

    String uri = API_LINK_V2 + "sign-in";
    Log.v("EXECUTING", uri);

    //Set up client
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    RequestBody requestBody = new MultipartBody.Builder()
            .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
            .addFormDataPart("username", email)
            .addFormDataPart("password", pass)
            .build();

    //Execute request
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(uri)
            .post(requestBody)
            .build();
    //Setup callback
    client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
            mhandler.post(() -> {
                if (mView != null) {
                    mView.showError();
                    mView.dismissLoadingDialog();
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, final Response response) throws IOException {
            final String res = Objects.requireNonNull(response.body()).string();
            mhandler.post(() -> {
                        try {
                            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                                JSONObject responeJsonObject = new JSONObject(res);
                                String token = responeJsonObject.getString("token");
                                mView.rememberUserInfo(token, email);
                                mView.startMainActivity();
                            } else {
                                mView.showError();
                            }
                            mView.dismissLoadingDialog();
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
            );
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Where exactly in your code are you using that the Toast that display that HTML message?

Comment: I didnot use any toast to display HTML message it is occuring due to the signup problem. https://github.com/project-travel-mate/Travel-Mate here is the project link. the signup is not working, any help would be greatful. Thankyou